# Themes in emacs-nox displaying bottom part of frame black instead of background color

Tags: init-file, themes, docker, emacs-nox

Edit: I tried many themes and it was an issue for all of them so this is not a Zenburn specific issue.

Edit: Docker is not part of the issue as there is the same behavior when this is done using just emacs-nox.

Edit:  In response to the comment from @caisah.
1) `M-x version` in `emacs-nox` outputs `GNU Emacs 24.5.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) of 2017-09-12 on hullmann, modified by Debian`.
2) I am running `emacs-nox` in [LXDE terminal emulator](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/lxterminal) version `0.2.0-1+deb8u1`.  I also tested it with lxterm and it is the same.
3) toggling full screen on and off and switching between maximize and iconify for `LXDE terminal editor` or `lxterm` did not make the black band at the bottom of the frame go away.

I am working on creating a `emacs-nox` development environment that works in a `docker` container.  I have added the `zenburn` theme and followed the instructions to deal with the ugly terminal color issue here:
https://github.com/bbatsov/zenburn-emacs#ugly-colors-in-the-terminal-emacs-version

In a `docker` container in `emacs-nox` `zenburn` is not being displayed the same way as in `emacs` (gui version).  The last column on the second last row and all of the last row are black instead of the background color of the rest of it.

Here is what it looks like in a `docker` container in `emacs-nox`:

[image]

Here is what I would like it to look like without the black section at the bottom:

[image]

Note: This second picture is in `emacs` and I know it will not look exactly the same in `emacs-nox`.  I would just like to get ride of the black section at the bottom and am showing this as counter example.

The relevant parts of the `.emacs` file are:

```
;; add zenburn theme
(use-package zenburn-theme
  :ensure t
  :pin melpa-stable)

;; add custom theme path
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/.emacs.d/themes/")

;; load zenburn theme on startup
(load-theme 'zenburn t)
```

The relevant parts of the `Dockerfile` are:

```
RUN echo "export TERM=xterm-256color" >> /root/.bashrc
```

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the theme but rather with the terminal or emacs running in the terminal. If you exit full screen the black band will disappear.

Comment: @caisah thanks for the comment.  Toggling full screen off and on did not fix this.  I added an edit to the question providing more information.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment @caisah provided I have been able to solve this issue.  I discovered the solution by playing with `guake` as an alternative to `LXDE terminal`.  It worked in right away with `guake` and the difference was that in the preferences for `LXDE terminal` I had the font size set to `20` while the default font size for `guake` was `10`.  I was able to get ride of the the issue with `LXDE terminal` as well when I also set the font size to `10`.

Here is what `emacs-nox` with the `Zenburn` theme running in `LXDE terminal` looks like when I change the font size to `10` in it's preferences.

[image]

As you can see this solves the issue of the bottom of the frame being black.  I can live with the last column of the last row being black.

However this solution brings up [another issue about font size](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/39392/changing-font-size-in-emacs-nox).